# Google-guice: bind all instances of the same class to certain instance

Tags: java, guice

I do not have a problem to bind singleton instance to some other instance using @inject.
But, when it comes to binding more instances of one class to some other instance (which is singletone) it refuses to bind it somehow and I'm getting null reference.

My code example is:

```
public class WebSocketManagerImpl implements WebSocketManager {
@Inject
private FactoryWebSocket factoryImpl;
}
```

When I create several instances of WebSocketManagerImpl, every factoryImpl field is null pointer.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is highly likely that you are not using an injector to create your classes. If you do `new WebSocketManagerImpl()` you *won`t* get injection. Guice is not that magical. Read excellent official documentation first: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation

Answer (score 0):

Please use Binding Annotations (https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).  This way you can annotate multiple instances of same class, and then have them selectively injected.